# I can't get data from HTML which is created by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use a jQuery to create a new HTML but when I use $.get or $.ajax methods it can't get that data ? 
For example I tested a simple jQuery :

```
$(function () {
    $(".tc3").html('<div id="test" ></div>');

    if($('.noprint a[href*="/f1-"]:first').length){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/f1-' ,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) { 
                d = $('#test', data).length;
                alert(d)
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

But when I try it alert the result is 0 . So why ? Thanks for reply

Comment: You sure that the page is returning any results

Comment: What does Firebug show in the console?  Also, what does `data.length` return?

Comment: The results that 0 only

Comment: I don't think `data` is a searchable DOM element.

Comment: I looked at your demo: http://codefm1.forumvi.com/t23-topic The html you get back from your ajax call (to `/f1-`) doesn't contain an element with the id of `test`, so `$('#test', data).length` is 0. Working as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I could be mistaken, I'm fairly certain your syntax is incorrect.

In the expression `$('#test', data)`, you are passing in `data` as the context to constrain what your selector, `#test`, can match.

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context):

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.
>   For example, to do a search within an event handler, the search can be
>   restricted like so:
>
> ```
> $( "div.foo" ).click(function() {
>   $(  "span", this ).addClass( "bar" );
> });
> ```
>
> When the search for the span selector is restricted to the context of
>   this, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional
>   class.
>
> Internally, selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method,
>   so  `$( "span", this )` is equivalent to `$( this ).find( "span" )`.

With this in mind, your above `data` object would have to be a DOM Element, Document, or jQuery object in order for it to correctly constrain the scope of the `#test` selector. Since `data` is unlikely to be any of these objects, the constraint will produce an invalid scope for `#test` to be found. Consequently, 0 is alerted.

Since I do not believe constraining the `#test` selector was your intent (after all there can only be one element with an id of `test` on a valid HTML page regardless of context), I can only assume you meant to append the contents of `data` to the `test` div. If my assumption is correct you should change your success method to:

```
success: function(data) { 
   var d = $('#test').html(data).length;
   alert(d);
}
```

In this case the length will be 1 since `html()` is chained to the initial `$('#test')` selector. And since there is only one element on the page with an Id of `test`, 1 will be alerted.

If instead you wanted the length of data, you can interrogate it directly with `data.length` which should give you the appropriate result depending on the object or string returned.

```
success: function(data) { 
   $('#test').html(data);

   var d = data.length;
   alert(d);
}
```

Lastly if `data` can be null, undefined, or otherwise falsy you can use `var d = data ? data.length : 0;` to ensure it always defaults to 0.

*NOTE: Aside from addressing your syntax, much of this answer is speculative as I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Adding more details to your question will help us better address your issue.*

Comment: Thanks for help but I try the first solution the result is 0 too, but the second it alert how many character of that page

Comment: What number are you expecting to see in the alert? What is `data` (a plain text string, an object, HTML)? Do you have an HTML element on your page with the class `tc3`?

Comment: When I searched your demo page I don't see any elements with a class of `tc3` so I can only conclude that `$(".tc3").html('<div id="test" ></div>');` never appended the div to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have both `#test` and `data` in the same jQuery selector?

Try

```
success : function(data){
   test = $("#test").length;
   d = data.length;
   alert("Test length: " + test + "\nData length: " + data);
}
```

Comment: It return the result 0 too . You can see demo : http://codefm1.forumvi.com/t23-topic

Comment: Then the issue is with the data return from the server.  Use firebug to see what exactly is being requested and in what format.

Answer (score 0):

What do you intend to do by passing data as second param to $('#test', data) ? The second param is the context in which the first param (selector) is evaluated. What are you returning from server in data? It has to be a parent of the '#test' selector for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If I take a look in your Javascript ( [codefm1.forumvi.com/99787.js](http://codefm1.forumvi.com/99787.js) ):

```
$(function(){

    $(".tc3").html('<div id="test" ></div>');
    if($('.noprint a[href*="/f1-"]:first').length){

        $.ajax({

            url:'/f1',
            type:'GET',
            success:function(data){

                test=$("#test").length;
                d=data.length;alert("Test length: "+test)
            }

        }
        )
    }

}
);
$(function(){
    $(".tc3").html('<div id="test" ></div>');if($('.noprint a[href*="/f4-"]:first').length){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/f4-',type:'GET',success:function(data){
                $('#test').html(data);var d=data.length;alert(d)
            }

        }
        )
    }

}
);
```

I see that your first `alert` only confirms that `#test` doesn't exist at this point yet. Try alerting `data.length` in the first ajax request instead of `$('#test').length`. If it still returns 0 then it means that nothing is returned.